# How to get my app's crash location?

Tags: c++, mfc

My operating system is Windows 7 on x64.

I am trying using a map file on my MFC application that I just simply made, that will crash when I click a CButton.

This map file says "Preferred load address is 00400000" and visual studio debugger says the crash location is **0x775015de**, which seems to be too big and so very wrong.

This might be because somewhat I don't see the correct crash location.

It would be great if I can figure out what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The crash may be caused by your program, but may be surfacing in a library that you don't use.  For instance, many Windows APIs will crash if you pass them invalid or bogus parameters.

Comment: Search for how to use visual studio for debugging. Hint: Press `F5`, look at the call stack tab, and hover your mouse over variables, once your program crashes and breaks into the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I looked into the call stack tab and it's from ntdll.dll. Then how could I get the crash location I want?

Comment: If you look up/down the `call stack` tab you should see a line with your code in it.  You should also do some reading about breakpoints.  ( Pressing `F9` in your code will put a breakpoint which the debugger will stop the program at when execution reaches that point. )

Comment: @Zac Thanks for the answer. I think I know how to debug using breakpoints and the call stack tab to find where the exception occurs. But it would be really great if I can succeed my debugging practice using ONLY the map file and execution file. It's actually from the book called Debugging Application .NET and Windows about "Debugging with map files". Thanks!

Comment: The book doesn't say about how to get the crash point showing where the crash got caused by my application, not any other WIN32 library. I didn't expect this would be tough either.

Comment: As @reuben pointed out, the crash is probably in a libraries api.  I've done this in the past for release builds, but recall it being rather painful.  If you are looking for post-motormen debugging you might consider using a pdb file & minidumps.  I believe I followed this when using the map file to debug: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3472/Finding-crash-information-using-the-MAP-file

Comment: @Zac I appreciate this. And as I'm not a native speaker, the word post-motormen means post-mortem? I just want to make my understanding accurate. Thanks! p.s I followed that link too.

Comment: @YayCplusplus, yes post-mortem is what I meant.  As a native English speaker I rely too much on the spell checker.  :-)

Comment: What do you mean by 'map file'? Are we talking memory mapped files here? What do you mean by "the map file says "Preferred load address is 00400000""?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toggle the break point and look at the call stack to see which function caused the program to crash if possible.